# How to fix "name 'render' is not defined" in Ursina Engine?

Tags: python, nameerror, ursina

So I've just started with "Ursina" Engine, I'm still very new to it. I'm trying to make a Minecraft game on Youtube tutorial with this Engine. And for some reason, the program keeps giving me the error name "Name 'render' is not defined". And I don't understand what that's saying. I tried to fix my code and skimmed over the code but couldn't find the answer.

This is all my code:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

Sky(texture = 'sky.jpg')

class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(
            model = 'cube',
            texture = 'white_cube',
            position = position,
            color = color.white,
            parent = scene,
            origin_y = 0.5,
            highlight_color = color.lime,
        )
    
app = Ursina()
player = FirstPersonController()
for x in range(12):
    for y in range(12):
        voxel = Voxel(position = (y,0,x))


app.run()
```

This is the Traceback of the code:

```
PS C:\Users\lhnguyen1029> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python39- 
32/python.exe" "c:/Users/lhnguyen1029/OneDrive - Mesa Public 
Schools/Documents/CTE- Computer Science Principles/Ursina 
practice/ursina_practice(2).py"
package_folder: 
C:\Users\lhnguyen1029\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\ursina
asset_folder: c:\Users\lhnguyen1029\OneDrive - Mesa Public 
Schools\Documents\CTE- Computer Science Principles\Ursina practice
screen resolution: (1366, 768)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\Users\lhnguyen1029\OneDrive - Mesa Public 
Schools\Documents\CTE- Computer Science Principles\Ursina 
practice\ursina_practice(2).py", line 7, in <module>
Sky(texture = 'sky.jpg')
File "C:\Users\lhnguyen1029\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\ursina\prefabs\sky.py", line 8, in __init__
parent = render,
NameError: name 'render' is not defined
PS C:\Users\lhnguyen1029>
```

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: also, what version of Ursina are you using?

Comment: I think it's the new version

Comment: To complete the QA cycle, please mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate Ursina() before instantiating entities.

Comment: Fixed it. I appreciate it.